# How to set timeout detection on a RabbitMQ server?

Tags: python, message-queue, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying out [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with [this](http://barryp.org/software/py-amqplib/) python binding.

One thing I noticed is that if I kill a consumer uncleanly (emulating a crashed program), the server will think that this consumer is still there for a long time. The result of this is that every other message will be ignored.

For example if you kill a consumer 1 time and reconnect, then 1/2 messages will be ignored. If you kill another consumer, then 2/3 messages will be ignored. If you kill a 3rd, then 3/4 messages will be ignored and so on.

I've tried turning on acknowledgments, but it doesn't seem to be helping. The only solution I have found is to manually stop the server and reset it.

Is there a better way?

**How to recreate this scenario**

- Run rabbitmq.
- Unarchive [this library](http://barryp.org/static/software/download/py-amqplib/0.6/amqplib-0.6.tgz).
- Download the consumer and publisher [here](http://blogs.digitar.com/jjww/code-samples/).
  Run amqp_consumer.py twice. Run amqp_publisher.py, feeding in some data and observe that it works as expected. Messages are received round robin style.
- Kill one of the consumer processes with kill -9 or task manager.
- Now when you publish a message, 50% of the messages will be lost.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of linux you were using

Comment: Good question — this is a critical issue if running behind a firewall or IP load-balancing appliance that drops idle sockets after N seconds, because neither RabbitMQ nor the client will ever be informed that the socket has gone away until they try using it.

Comment: I do have exact same issue with RabbitMQ 3.2.1 and puka. Seems there is still no good solution for that.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see `amqp_consumer.py` or `amqp_producer.py` in the tarball, so reproducing the fault is tricky.

RabbitMQ terminates connections, releasing their unacknowledged messages for redelivery to other clients, whenever it is told by the operating system that a socket has closed. Your symptoms are very strange, in that even a `kill -9` ought to cause the TCP socket to be cleaned up properly.

Some people have noticed problems with sockets surviving longer than they should when running with a firewall or NAT device between the AMQP clients and the server. Could that be an issue here, or are you running everything on localhost? Also, what operating system are you running the various components of the system on?

**ETA:** From your comment below, I am guessing that while you are running the server on Linux, you may be running the clients on Windows. If this is the case, then it could be that the Windows TCP driver is not closing the sockets correctly, which is different from the kill-9 behaviour on Unix. (On Unix, the kernel will properly close the TCP connections on any killed process.)

If that's the case, then the **bad news** is that RabbitMQ can only release resources when the socket is closed, so if the client operating system doesn't do that, there's nothing it can do. This is the same as almost every other TCP-based service out there.

The **good news**, though, is that AMQP supports a "heartbeat" option for exactly these cases, where the networking fabric is untrustworthy. You could try enabling heartbeats. When they're enabled, if the server doesn't receive any traffic within a configurable interval, it decides that the connection must be dead.

The **bad news**, however, is that I don't think py-amqplib supports heartbeats at the moment. Worth a try, though!

Comment: Sorry about that. The producer and consumer is here http://blogs.digitar.com/jjww/code-samples/

Comment: I am running rabbitmq on a remote linux server while I am running the producer and consumer. I realize that the socket may not have been closed cleanly, but that is exactly what I want to emulate. I was testing to see how rabbitmq handles crashed processes which may not have closed the socket cleanly, and unfortunately it doesn't seems to handle this very well.

Comment: @Tony; how does one enable the "heartbeat" option within the RabbitMQ server (within /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config for example)?

Comment: Never mind, I understand now that this is configured client-side.

Answer (score 5):

RabbitMQ doesn't have a timeout on acknowledgements from the client that a message has been processed: see [this post](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2009-March/003158.html) (the whole thread might be of interest). Some salient points from the post:

> The AMQP ack model for subscriptions
>   and "pull" are identical. In both 
>   cases the message is kept on the
>   server but is unavailable to other 
>   consumers until it either has been
>   ack'ed (and gets removed), nack'ed 
>   (with basic.reject; though RabbitMQ
>   does not implement that) or the 
>   channel/connection is closed (at which
>   point the message becomes  available
>   to other consumers).

and (my emphases)

> There is no timeout on waiting for
>   acks. Usually that is not a problem 
>   **since the common cases of a missing
>   ack - network or client failure - 
>   will result in the connection getting
>   dropped** (and thus trigger the 
>   behaviour described above). Still,
>   a timeout could be useful to, say, 
>   deal with **alive but unresponsive
>   consumers**. That has come up in 
>   discussion before. Is there a specific
>   use case you have in mind that 
>   requires such functionality?

The problem might well be occurring because in a client pull model, it's harder for the server to detect a broken connection (as opposed to an alive but unresponsive consumer), particularly as the server seems happy to wait forever for an ack.

**Update:** On Linux, you can attach signal handlers for SIGTERM and/or SIGKILL and/or SIGINT and hopefully close down the connection in an orderly way from the client. On Windows, I believe closing from Task Manager invokes the Win32 `TerminateProcess` API, about which MSDN says:

> If a process is terminated by
>   `TerminateProcess`, all threads of the
>   process are terminated immediately
>   with no chance to run additional code.
>   This means that the thread does not
>   execute code in termination handler
>   blocks. In addition, no attached DLLs
>   are notified that the process is
>   detaching.

This means it might be difficult to catch termination and close down in an orderly way.

It might be worth pursuing on the RabbitMQ list with your own use case for an ack timeout.

Comment: According to that mailing list, if the consumer terminates the connection, it should operate correctly. However, kill -9 or end process in taskmanager should also terminate the connection in that manner. But it still doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide a few more specifics regarding the components you've declared. Usually (and independent of the the client implementation) a queue with the properties

- exclusive and
- auto-delete

should get removed as soon as the connection between the declaring client and the broker breaks up. This won't help you with shared queues, though. Please detail a bit what exactly you are trying to model.

Comment: I am not talking about when queues get deleted. I am talking about how rabbitmq doesn't detect crashed connections for a very long time and keeps trying to send them messages as though they are still there.